# Error while installing libgpg-error

Tags: mingw

I am trying to install vmime on windows, so I am following this tutorial http://web.archive.org/web/20151201200805/http://vmime.omgwtfbbq.nl/
I got to the point where I have to install libgpg-error-1.27, so I entered the commands as mentioned in the tuto, changing the version ofc, all is fine until I run make, it shows these errors

```
$make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27'
Making all in m4
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27/m4'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27/m4'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27/src'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -
DLOCALEDIR=\"/mingw/share/locale\"  -I/mingw/include  -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-
arith -Wno-psabi -MT libgpg_error_la-w32-estream.lo -MD -MP -MF 
.deps/libgpg_error_la-w32-estream.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-w32-estream.lo 
`test -f 'w32-estream.c' || echo './'`w32-estream.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -
DLOCALEDIR=\"/mingw/share/locale\" -I/mingw/include -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-
arith -Wno-psabi -MT libgpg_error_la-w32-estream.lo -MD -MP -MF 
.deps/libgpg_error_la-w32-estream.Tpo -c w32-estream.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o 
.libs/libgpg_error_la-w32-estream.o
w32-estream.c: In function '_gpgrt_w32_poll':
w32-estream.c:779:8: warning: variable 'waitinfo' set but not used [-Wunused-
but-set-variable]
   char waitinfo[MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS];
        ^~~~~~~~
w32-estream.c: In function 'func_w32_pollable_seek':
w32-estream.c:1012:23: error: 'EOPNOTSUPP' undeclared (first use in this 
function)
   _gpg_err_set_errno (EOPNOTSUPP);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
w32-estream.c:1012:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once 
for each function it appears in
w32-estream.c: In function 'func_w32_pollable_ioctl':
w32-estream.c:1038:23: error: 'EOPNOTSUPP' undeclared (first use in this 
function)
   _gpg_err_set_errno (EOPNOTSUPP);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [libgpg_error_la-w32-estream.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/usr/libgpg-error-1.27'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to install older versions of libgpg-error but it gives errors too.
I must say that I know nothing about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today; after some research I managed to compile it after simply adding

```
#define EOPNOTSUPP 45
```

at the top of w32-estream.c.